# Showing that $X(t)=\int_0^tB(s)ds $ is a Gaussian process.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

The time integration of Brownian motion is given by $X(t)=\int_0^tB(s)ds$. In order to show that  $X(t)$ is a gaussian process I work with the definition that  for any $t_0<t_1 < t_2<\ldots <t_{n-1}$ the random variable

$$ \langle v,(X_{t_0}, ... , X_{t_{n-1}}) \rangle $$

is again Gaussian.

I tried to write out the quantity in terms of Riemann sums i.e.

$$ X(t) = \lim_{n\to {\infty}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}B(t_k)(t_{k+1}-t_k) $$
But got stuck with all the indices, how to continue?

We can assume that limits of gaussian random variables are again Gaussian.

Comment: Thanks for the reaction, no since there it is only shown that the $X(t)$ is Gaussian but I want to show that $\{X(t) ,t \geq 0\}$ is a gaussian process and for that it is not sufficient to show that $X(t)$ is gaussian.

Comment: Wouldn't the same argument show that any finite family $\bigl(X(t_1),\ldots,X(t_n)\bigr)$ forms a Gaussian vector?

Comment: If you could additionaly show that $X(t_1),...,X(t_n)$ are independent then yes, but I don't see how. Maybe by the independence of increments of brownian motion?

Comment: No, I mean if you write
$$\left(X(t_1),\ldots,X(t_k)\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\Bigl(S^1_n,\ldots,S^k_n\Bigr)$$
where each $S^i_n$ is a Riemann sum from $B$ converging to $X(t_i)$, then like so the left-hand side is a limit of Gaussian vectors.

Comment: What is $v$ in your example?

Comment: @Thomas $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: So the first expression indicates a generic linear combination of the X variables?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, that's right!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using integration by parts we get:
$$X(t) = t B(t) - \int_0^ts dB(s)$$
Recall that the Itô integral of a deterministic function is a Gaussian process; thus $X(t)$ is the linear combination of two Gaussian process, making it Gaussian itself.

---

**Edit:** We can prove this without directly appealing to results from Itô calculus (as requested in the comments). Using [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts), we get: $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}B(t_{k+1})(t_{k+1} - t_k) = B(t_n)t_n - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} t_k(B(t_{k+1})- B(t_{k}))$$
The right hand side can be seen to be a Gaussian process; sending $n \to \infty$ we get that $X(t)$ is a Gaussian process.

Comment: Thanks Jose, but would it also be possible to show without Ito - Calculus?

Comment: @Keep_On_Cruising Yes, see my edit.

Comment: Why can the right hand side be seen as a Gaussian process?

Comment: @Keep_On_Cruising It's a linear combination of independent Gaussian random variables.

Comment: On the left for finite n we have a sum of dependent gaussian variables, that should be Gaussian as well. Isn't the problem more in checking that the limit of large n conserves the Gaussian behavior?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, although the OP mentioned "We can assume that limits of gaussian random variables are again Gaussian." The proof of that is elementary by considering characteristic functions.

Comment: Ah ok perfect I did not read that part... but than couldn't you just say that for finite n the sum on the left is gaussian ( since the joint of B(tk) is multivariate gaussian ) and invoke the property? Why did you have to do the summation by parts trick?

Comment: @Thomas That is correct too, after noting that the $B(t_k)$s are jointly Gaussian. For this answer, I wanted to show that the integration by parts trick could be done without Itô calculus.

Comment: @JoseAvilez yes but that does only show that brownian motion is a gaussian process not $X(t)$ right? For that you would need to consider a linear combination of $X(t_i)$

Comment: @Keep_On_Cruising Choose a vector of times $s - (s_1, \ldots , s_r)$ and evaluate $\langle s, (X(s_1), \ldots , X(s_r))\rangle$ using either formula above. You'll notice this is a linear combination of jointly Gaussian RVs, hence Gaussian, thus showing $X$ is a Gaussian process.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a more explicit way is sketched here, using directly the definition and w.o. integration by parts.

We have to show that $X(z_1),...,X(z_k)$ is jointly Gaussian, by definition of Gaussian process.

We can choose a partition of the time variable $u_{0}=0,...,u_{M}$ such that $u_{N_1}=z_1,...,u_{N_k}=z_k$ (that is, we have a partition that contains $z_1,..,z_k$). Call this partition $\Delta$.

The partition defines the approximations $X^{\Delta}(z_1),...,X^{\Delta}(z_k)$ in the standard way. We observe that these approximations are a finite combination of jointly distributed Gaussian ramdom variabless, therefore:

- $X^{\Delta}(z_1)=Z_0$ is Gaussian
- $X^{\Delta}(z_2)=X^{\Delta}(z_1)+Z_1$ , where $Z_1$ is Gaussian and $(Z_0,Z_1)$ have a joint Gaussian distribution

This shows that $(X^{\Delta}(z_1),X^{\Delta}(z_2))\sim(Z_0,Z_0+Z_1)$ is jointly Gaussian as well.

Analogously:

- $X^{\Delta}(z_3)=X^{\Delta}(z_2)+Z_2=X^{\Delta}(z_1)+Z_1+Z_2=$, where $Z_0,Z_1$,$Z_2$ are jointly Gaussian distributed.

This shows that $(X^{\Delta}(z_1),X^{\Delta}(z_2),X^{\Delta}(z_3)) \sim (Z_0,Z_0+Z_1,Z_0+Z_1+Z_2)$.

, and so on...

Now taking the limit $\Delta \rightarrow 0$ in $L^2$ (the one needed to define the Ito integral), if we know that the limit of a sequence of (multivariate) Gaussian variables is (multivariate) Gaussian (that we can take for granted according to the OP), we have shown that the resulting joint distribution of the limit process is Gaussian.

Comment: Good sketch, +1